# Multiple divs in multiple lines, but on the same position

Tags: html, css

I need to do multiple divs but they must be in the same line on the same position. I really don't know how to say it in english. Here what I exactly need, so I mean I need this:

```
X     X
X     X
X
```

But currently I have this:

```
X  x
 X  x
  X
```

My code:

```css
.buy-one {
      -moz-column-count: 2;
        -webkit-column-count: 2;
        column-count: 2;
     }
    
     .buy-text {
      display: inline-block;
      font-family: 'Open Sans', sans-serif;
      font-size: 14px;
      font-weight: 600;
     }
     
     .buy-img {
      display: inline-block;
      vertical-align: middle;
     }
```

```html
  <div class="buy">
           <div class="buy-one" style="display:block;">
            <div style="display: block; clear: both;">
             <img class="buy-img" src="" alt="zdjecie">
             <p class="buy-text">xyz.</p>
         </div>
                        <div style="display: block; clear: both;">
             <img class="buy-img" src="" alt="zdjecie">
             <p class="buy-text">xyz.</p>
         </div>
                       <div style="display: block; clear: both;">
             <img class="buy-img" src="" alt="zdjecie">
             <p class="buy-text">xyz.</p>
         </div>
           </div>
          </div>
```

Comment: Do you have and styles applied to this html code? If so - show them, otherwise there is no meaning in the question

Comment: You might want to learn a bit about [flexbox](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/)

Comment: i did an update

Comment: @Programmer actually your own code seems to work fine: https://codepen.io/anon/pen/vebRxJ so what is actual problem?

Comment: When you write in one box more in another so it displays bad

Comment: Go to flexbox solution then, I've [updated](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/vebRxJ) my example.

Answer (score 0):

Is this what your looking for , let me know.

```css
.buy-one {
  -moz-column-count: 2;
  -webkit-column-count: 2;
  column-count: 2;
  background-color: lightgreen;
}

.buy-text {
  display: inline-flex;
  font-family: 'Open Sans', sans-serif;
  font-size: 14px;
  font-weight: 600;
}

.buy-img {
  display: inline-flex;
  vertical-align: middle;
}
```

```html
<div class="buy">
  <div class="buy-one" style="display:block;">
    <div style="display: block; clear: both;">
      <img class="buy-img" src="https://www.gravatar.com/avatar/7e1dd083be890b04a3c082fecdd31310?s=32&d=identicon&r=PG&f=1" alt="zdjecie">
      <p class="buy-text">xyz.</p>
    </div>
    <div style="display: block; clear: both;">
      <img class="buy-img" src="https://www.gravatar.com/avatar/7e1dd083be890b04a3c082fecdd31310?s=32&d=identicon&r=PG&f=1" alt="zdjecie">
      <p class="buy-text">xyz.</p>
    </div>
    <div style="display: block; clear: both;">
      <img class="buy-img" src="https://www.gravatar.com/avatar/7e1dd083be890b04a3c082fecdd31310?s=32&d=identicon&r=PG&f=1" alt="zdjecie">
      <p class="buy-text">xyz.</p>
    </div>
    <div style="display: block; clear: both;">
      <img class="buy-img" src="https://www.gravatar.com/avatar/7e1dd083be890b04a3c082fecdd31310?s=32&d=identicon&r=PG&f=1" alt="zdjecie">
      <p class="buy-text">xyz.</p>
    </div>
    <div style="display: block; clear: both;">
      <img class="buy-img" src="https://www.gravatar.com/avatar/7e1dd083be890b04a3c082fecdd31310?s=32&d=identicon&r=PG&f=1" alt="zdjecie">
      <p class="buy-text">xyz.</p>
    </div>
    <div style="display: block; clear: both;">
      <img class="buy-img" src="https://www.gravatar.com/avatar/7e1dd083be890b04a3c082fecdd31310?s=32&d=identicon&r=PG&f=1" alt="zdjecie">
      <p class="buy-text">xyz.</p>
    </div>
    <div style="display: block; clear: both;">
      <img class="buy-img" src="https://www.gravatar.com/avatar/7e1dd083be890b04a3c082fecdd31310?s=32&d=identicon&r=PG&f=1" alt="zdjecie">
      <p class="buy-text">xyz.</p>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Cross-posting from comment above:

```css
.buy-item {
  /* just for better visibility */
  border: 2px solid lightgreen;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.buy-one {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  width: 100%;
}
.buy-item {
  flex: 0 0 50%;
}

    .buy-text {
        display: inline-block;
        font-family: 'Open Sans', sans-serif;
        font-size: 14px;
        font-weight: 600;
    }

    .buy-img {
        display: inline-block;
        vertical-align: middle;
    }
```

```html
<div class="buy">
                <div class="buy-one">
                    <div class="buy-item">
                        <img class="buy-img" src="" alt="zdjecie">
                        <p class="buy-text">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Fusce euismod ligula sit amet ex imperdiet, vitae ullamcorper eros volutpat. Aenean vehicula vestibulum sapien, quis finibus orci malesuada et. Cras sodales bibendum neque, vitae volutpat odio feugiat ac. Nulla aliquam enim maximus ligula vehicula congue. In faucibus mollis semper. Nunc sed scelerisque mi, quis cursus arcu. Fusce sed sem sed quam eleifend commodo id eget lorem. Nullam tristique tellus ac sapien ultrices, porttitor volutpat est consequat. </p>
                    </div>
                    <div class="buy-item">
                        <img class="buy-img" src="" alt="zdjecie">
                        <p class="buy-text">xyz.</p>
                    </div>
                   <div class="buy-item">
                        <img class="buy-img" src="" alt="zdjecie">
                        <p class="buy-text">xyz.</p>
                    </div>
                   <div class="buy-item">
                        <img class="buy-img" src="" alt="zdjecie">
                        <p class="buy-text">Nullam id justo congue, luctus nulla a, tempus sapien. Cras ante felis, fringilla at interdum nec, euismod nec ante. In hac habitasse platea dictumst. Donec non tortor quis diam convallis aliquet. Proin feugiat, nisi id accumsan feugiat, libero neque porttitor sapien, sed porta nunc purus vel nibh. Donec in est enim. In ac mauris ligula. Morbi urna nunc, malesuada quis interdum nec, congue non turpis. Nam tincidunt nibh diam, quis vulputate mi bibendum eget. Duis eu finibus nibh. Praesent placerat ut nunc id rutrum. Vestibulum at bibendum eros. Morbi tellus turpis, accumsan a facilisis at, accumsan vitae nulla. Aliquam malesuada placerat consectetur.</p>
                    </div>
                   <div class="buy-item">
                        <img class="buy-img" src="" alt="zdjecie">
                        <p class="buy-text">xyz.</p>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

```css
  /*.buy-one {
        -moz-column-count: 2;
        -webkit-column-count: 2;
        column-count: 2;
    }*/

    .buy-text {
        display: inline-block;
        font-family: 'Open Sans', sans-serif;
        font-size: 14px;
        font-weight: 600;
    }

    .buy-img {
        display: inline-block;
        vertical-align: middle;
    }
```

```html
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">



<body>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
 <div class="buy">
                <div class="buy-one" style="display:block;">
                    <div style="display: block; float:left; width:300px;">
                        <img class="buy-img" src="" alt="zdjecie">
                        <p class="buy-text">xyz.</p>
                    </div>
                    <div style="display: block;">
                        <img class="buy-img" src="" alt="zdjecie">
                        <p class="buy-text">xyz.</p>
                    </div>
                   <div style="display: block;">
                        <img class="buy-img" src="" alt="zdjecie">
                        <p class="buy-text">xyz.</p>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div

</body>
</html>
```

try to remove the buy-one css class:

```css
  /*.buy-one {
        -moz-column-count: 2;
        -webkit-column-count: 2;
        column-count: 2;
    }*/

    .buy-text {
        display: inline-block;
        font-family: 'Open Sans', sans-serif;
        font-size: 14px;
        font-weight: 600;
    }

    .buy-img {
        display: inline-block;
        vertical-align: middle;
    }
```

```html
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">



<body>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
 <div class="buy">
                <div class="buy-one" style="display:block;">
                    <div style="display: block; clear: both;">
                        <img class="buy-img" src="" alt="zdjecie">
                        <p class="buy-text">xyz.</p>
                    </div>
                    <div style="display: block; clear: both;">
                        <img class="buy-img" src="" alt="zdjecie">
                        <p class="buy-text">xyz.</p>
                    </div>
                   <div style="display: block; clear: both;">
                        <img class="buy-img" src="" alt="zdjecie">
                        <p class="buy-text">xyz.</p>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score -1):

Here you will get example and you can grab any one that suites you.

http://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/examples/

Comment: i need clean css